# Cannot login to a local ASP.NET app after publishing it to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an `ASP.NET` Core application with `Visual Studio 2015` Update 3. The app, as generated by the Visual Studio wizard, was published by using the menu Build, option Publish. I entered the data requested by VS, and the app was published in my Azure account.

When creating the app, I chose the option "Work and school account" authentication, meaning that I can login with my Azure/Office 365 user account.

So far, it works great, and the app can be accessed by the URL provided by Azure.

However, now, when I try to run/debug the app in my local IIS Express, I do get an error when logging in. The error shows [Microsoft's standard page](http://login.microsoftonline.com). The error I get is the following:

Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

We received a bad request.

> Additional technical information:
>   Correlation ID: 92884f38-bbfb-4dbb-8224-58ac95ff3cdc
>   Timestamp: 2016-12-06 06:17:02Z
>   AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '5c8c803c-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' was not found in the directory 7d3523a5-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

The 5c GUID refers to my application ClientID in Azure, and the 7d GUID refers to the Tenant ID. I checked my Azure tenant, and the Active Directory has my app registered. The only difference is that the URL points to myapp.azurewebsites.net, and when running from my local IIS, the URL is localhost.

Does this difference in URLs have something to do? What can I do to fix this?

How is this type of application usually debugged without having to publish the app any time I make a change?

Comment: You need two entries in the AzureAD. One for your local application and one for your live application and use i.e. environment variables to override the value set in appsettings.json. you can only set up one return url so it can be either local or your production domain but not both

Comment: Hi @Tseng thank you for your input. When you say two entries, do you refer to two application registrations? As for the appsettings.json, do I have to change the values manually each time I debug/publish, or is there some sort if conditional preprocessing (akin to #if DEBUG use these settings #else use these other)?

Comment: Yes, two application registrations. You can leave the fields blank in appsettings.json. For development use user secrets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets for development use `.UseEnvironmentVariables` and set the environmental variable inside Azure Web Service page in the Azure Portal

Comment: Thank you, @Tseng I'll give it a try, I'll let you know later. Thank you for the link, I wasn't aware of the "secrets" fuctionality in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add localhost to **Reply URLs** of your application in Azure.

Take a look here:
[image]

and here:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dawid Rutkowski, thank you for your input. I tried what you suggested, I added the Reply URL, but it is still not working. Do I have to change anything else in my app or in Azure? Thank you again!

Comment: You can check once again if you properly copied all of the GUID as exception message "was not found in the directory" may suggest that App Identifier or Tenant Id are wrong.